# OBSOLETE - How should I understand "timeline_type": "votes" record in question timeline?

Tags: support, status-norepro, questions, obsolete, api-v1

Take a look at the partial results of [this query](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/2544008/timeline?type=jsontext&pagesize=100):

```
{
  "timeline_type": "votes",
  "post_id": 2544061,
  "creation_date": 1269993600,
  "owner": {
    // omitted for brevity
  },
  "action": "7 upvotes"
},
```

I'm sure the answer pointed out by this record never had 7 upvotes and there are no similar records for other answers.

So what does "action": "7 upvotes" mean?

Comment: Closing this question as it applies to a beta version of the API and the issue can no longer be replicated.